# Cross Join on two different tables in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, cross-join

I have two data tables in Spotfire and the data source of these datatables is CSV. I want to add columns from one datatable to another based on Cross Join.

If the datatables source is Information Link I would have modified the sql in the Information designer but these are flat files how do i manipulate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read in the tables, add calculated columns to each table and call them `cross_join_criterion`. For the expression, just enter `1`. Click Insert, then Columns. When you match columns, make sure that the only ones you're matching in both tables is `cross_join_criterion`. Choose Full Outer as the join type.

You need to add the calculated columns when importing the data because Spotfire won't allow you to use a calculated column made after the data has been imported as a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

from the main menu click Insert >> Columns. use the options there to complete the join.

Comment: Hi Niko,thanks for your update but there is no "Cross Join" in the options.